# How to implement one outgoing IP for few instances

Tags: proxy, haproxy

Few days I'm trying to find solution and experimenting, but seems without help I can't.

There is cluster of servers, those servers will do lots of outgoing requests and all those requests must have one outgoing IP address.

My colleague has adviced me HAProxy, but at the moment I can implement only load balancer (one access point).

I'm open for other solutions :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If these servers happen to be AWS, this question has been [answered at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/760093/153161).  HAProxy is a  valid solution for originating traffic outbound, from a fixed address, to a specific external destination, as long as the external destination is known in advance.  It is not useful for sending requests to arbitrary destinations.  It isn't clear what you mean by *"at the moment I can implement only load balancer (one access point)."*

Comment: It is very clear I think :) Main advantage of HAProxy is load balancing.

Comment: Regarding to your link, question has been answered but it won't help me, my instances should be in public subnet. It's not possible to use NAT and public subnet as I know.

Comment: *"Main advantage of HAProxy is load balancing"*...that is presumably the most common application, but I do also use HAProxy to solve exactly the issue this question is about -- so that my application servers can access a specific 3rd party server, known in advancr, from a fixed IP address by connecting to the local HAProxy, whose front-end listens inside and back-end connects outside. It has the further advantage of concentrating access logging for troubleshootig in one place. If you will confirm that this is your use case, I can explain further.

Comment: *"my instances should be in public subnet."* It's a common assumption that instances behind an ELB should be in a public subnet, but that isn't actually necessary (mine never are). I don't know if you have other reasons why they should be in a public subnet, however,  *"It's not possible to use NAT and public subnet as I know"* is also generally but not entirely right. If you wanted to route traffic bound for (example) 203.0.113.123 through a NAT instance or gateway, that is possible from a public subnet, with VPC route tables, with the NAT device in a *different* publc subnet.

Comment: good, that you know how to do that, I don't

Comment: I have presented two alternatives, implicitly offering to explain one or both of them in an answer, if they are if interest to you.